# What is the performance of filling and showing a very large customer class

Tags: c#, list, datagridview

If you have a customer class with 85 properties and you assign each property with a valu for 5000 customers, then add each customer to a list so you can show each costomer in a datagridview. How long should this process take from when pressing down a button and assigning the first customer until all the 5000 customers has been assigned a value and shown in the gridview?

I want to know how many minutes doese it to assign 85 properties for 5000 customers, then add the customers to a list and shows them in a gridview.

EDIT: Here is some code:

```
    private string customerID;
    public string CustomerID
    {
        get { return customerID; }
        set { customerID= value; }
    }
    private int username;
    public int UserName
    {
        get { return username; }
        set { username= value; }
    }
    private string adress;
    public string Adress
    {
        get { return adress; }
        set { adress= value; }
    }
```

In another class i use while and switch-statement to assign these values. In the while-statement, as long as there is customers i use a switch-statement like this:

```
               switch (customers)
                {
                    case "Customer ID":
                        try
                        {
                            cust.CustomerID = customerid;
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                        }
                        break;
                    case "User Name":
                        try
                        {
                            cust.UserName = username;
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                        }
                        break;
                    case "Adress":
                        try
                        {
                            cust.Adress = adress;
                        }
                        catch ()
                        {

                        }
                        break;
```

I assign the customer properties like this.

Comment: That obviously depends on your hardware. I'd suggest you write the code and measure its actual performance on your target machine.

Comment: I have measured and it take about 11 minutes to assign the first cutomer with all its properties to costumer number 5000. Is this a normal time?

Comment: The I/O will be the major part, and you don't mention where the data is coming from...

Comment: @Lars: show your code. That's a ridiculous long time, perhaps the propery's settor is slow? You're talking of assigning, not showing them. Do you set your properties to "a value" (as in your question) or to data from somewhere else? How large are the 85 properties combined (in bytes)? Do you show it on a GridView (ASP.NET) or DataGridView (WinForms)?

Comment: You might want to post your specific code to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ site and ask there for possible performance improvement suggestions.

Comment: Those try-blocks would be wrong even without the empty catch blocks. Do yourself a favour and remove all of them. Nothing to do with the speed though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real answer to your question: it depends.

I'd oppose the design of such a system, use lazy loading and paging instead. But suppose you'd do it, we can make a little calculation (change the numbers to your actual values):

### Memory considerations

- 85 properties have to be assigned, let's say with 16 bytes, than this makes 1360 bytes
- A list contains pointers to each item, this makes 1360 + 4 (or 1360 + 8) = 1364 bytes
- 5000 * 1364 = 6820000
- Display in a DataGridView: overhead per row about 4000 bytes (you have to test this for yourself, part of it may be stored depending on scrolling): 27280000000 =
- That is 26GB

Now, I have a system with 64GB inside, 64 bits. It might take as little as a few seconds (assuming I won't scroll). Filling the 5000 rows can be less than a few milliseconds though, even on an average system (5000 records is not much).

Any system that doesn't have enough memory available will start paging (swapping to the physical page file). This becomes very slow, orders of magnitude. Remember that when playing with relatively large datasets.

Note: I assumed everything was random and you tried measuring the speed of the object itself. But if your data comes from a disk, a remote database or worse, a web service, this can take any time from seconds to hours.

### Active directory

EDIT: in a late comment under Darin's answer, you talk about Active Directory. This is remote and your speed will likely depend more on AD than anything else. Add paging (i.e., only load what you want to show) and you should get reasonable performance.

### Your code

You show a bit of your code. The try/catch around the settors: they don't do anything, there's nothing to catch. In terms of performance: you just showed the part that's not performance critical (unless any of those strings are huge, see my memory section above). The part that *is* slow, is your AD part.

### Conclusion (so far)

Reconsider your design. Read the data in chunks of 10 or 20 records, and only request those fields / properties from AD that are actually needed to show. You can't show them all at once anyway. DataGridView has excellent features for paging, I suggest you use the paging events in combination with better loading of the data.

In answer to your remark about it suddenly taking much more time above 5000 records: measure the performance counters of each system, check memory, page faults, network. Or just don't read above 5000 records at once.

Comment: If the users in the AD is less than a 1000, the process does not take alot of time, but if the users are over 5000 the process takes about 11 minutes for me, I dont know if its because of my code or if its because of the response from the AD.

Answer (score 4):

No idea how much time it will take, you should measure it. All I can say is that showing 5000 records in a grid on a single page is bad from ergonomic perspective. I would recommend you implementing a paging.

Comment: I'm not sure how a user is supposed to update 85 properties in a single row and still keep their sanity.

Comment: I wont shows all of them in the grid, just some of them. But i wanted to know how much time it should take.

Comment: @Lars, the [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class can help you measure the time to process it on the server. Of course there are other factors that should be taken into account for the global UI experience such as network latencies, client browsers, ...

Comment: I have measured and it take about 11 minutes to assign the first cutomer with all its properties to costumer number 5000. Is this a normal time?

Comment: @Lars, no, that's not normal time, at least from my point of view. If you was an user, would you wait 11 minutes for a web page to load? For me every web page that takes more than a second to load is considered as bad. And processes that are supposed to take more time simply shouldn't be implemented as web pages.

Comment: But this is not a web page :S, iam talking about getting 5000 users from Active Directory and then add them to a list and inserts them to a database. What would be a normal time?

Comment: @Lars, so why are you talking about a gridview then?